# Calculating the number of nodes in a tree when each level has diffrent number of nodes

Tags: tree, binary-tree, computer-science, nodes

Let's say have we this kind of tree:
http://up400.siz.co.il/up1/tymmh2wylmmo.png

When the height of the tree is some H, and each level in the tree can have different number of nodes.
For example, the root level has 3 nodes ("x" in the picture), the next level each node has 2 nodes("y" in the picture), the next level each node has 4 nodes ("z" in the picture), and so on...

Is there any formula for calculating these kind of trees, when the H is given, and the number of nodes (for each node) is given?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The recursive formula is obvious:

```
def node_count(level):
    n = number_of_children_for_level(level)
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + n * node_count(level + 1)
```

supposing that the number of children for level are `3, 4, 2, 0` the total number of nodes will be

```
1 + 3 * (1 + 4 * (1 + 2 * 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tree is complete, then...

- The subtree below each leaf has 1 node.
- The subtree below each second-level node has 1 * 4 + 1 = 5 nodes.
- The subtree below each third-level node has 5 * 2 + 1 = 11 nodes.
- The complete tree has 11 * 3 + 1 = 34 nodes.

So the general formula would be ((((m + 1) * n + 1) ... * p + 1) * q + 1), where m...q are the number of nodes on each level. Or you could say recursively that `size_n = size_{n - 1} * branchiness_n + 1`.